Use Custom Manager to Filter on a Reverse Relation
I have a set of users and a set of assignments each user submits.
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Assignment(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(
    "User",
    related_name="assignments"
  )
  status = models.CharField()

  approved = AssignmentActiveManager()
  rejected = AssignmentRejectedManager()
  ...

I created custom managers to determine different states of assignments, as it's complex and should be internal to the model. For example:
class AssignmentActiveManager()
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Assignment.objects.filter(status__in=["Approved", "Accepted"])

Now I want to get all users with an approved assignment, using the Assignment.approved manager, because I don't want to duplicate the filtering code.
I can do
Users.objects.filter(assignments__in=Assignments.approved.all()).all()

However, this query involves a WHERE status IN (SELECT ...) subquery. This is going to be less efficient than the query generated if I had written the filtering explicitly:
Users.objects.filter(assignments__status__in=["Approved", "Accepted"]).all()

Which would do an INNER JOIN and WHERE user.assignment_id IN (Approved, Accepted).
So my question is: Is there a way to select users by filtering on assignments using the Assignment custom managers efficiently?

Users.objects.filter(assignments__status__in=["Approved", "Accepted"]).distinct()?

@willeM_VanOnsem, I don't want selections on the User class to refer to the specific statuses on Assignments which are approved. The logic of an assignment being approved should be constrained to the Assignment class.

Why not move filtering in a utility function that you can use for both cases.

I'm not sure I understand. What would the filter function return? A queryset? I want to both filter for Users with any "approved" assignments, and I want to filter for approved assignments, which is why I suggested the hypothetical reuse of the managers. I want to abstract what it means to be an approved assignment to a single place in the codebase.

This looks more like a custom lookup, we can do this by subclassing a CharField:
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.lookups import In, Lookup


class StatusField(CharField):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [('a', 'Approved'), ('z', 'Accepted')]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('choices', self.STATUS_CHOICES)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Active(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'active'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        expr = In(self.lhs, ['a', 'z'])
        if not self.rhs:
            expr = ~expr
        return expr.as_sql(compiler, connection)


StatusField.register_lookup(Active)
and now we can use the StatusField instead:
class Assignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='assignments')
    status = StatusField()
   # …
and filter both items with:
Assignment.objects.filter(status__active=True)  # active assignment
User.objects.filter(assignments__status__active=False)  # at least one inactive assignment
which thus allows more declarative filtering.


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.


This looks like a potential solution. After I take a closer look I'll respond with more detailed comments. With respect to AUTH_USER_MODEL, I was using User and Assignment as simpler examples of the objects I am dealing with. They aren't actual users nor assignments.

Is User.objects.filter(assignments__active=False) supposed to be User.objects.filter(assignments__status__active=True)? for "at least one active assignment"

@EnricoBorba: yes, fixed.
